# Time derivative of angular velocity in rotating reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differentiation, angular-velocity

I am going through a section in a textbook regarding the Newton Euler equations for a system of rigid bodies (robotics text). There is a particular line in the derivation I don't understand, I've attached the image to make it clear:

[image]

I think the derivative of the second term on the right-hand side of 3.28 is using the product rule to get to 3.32, but I don't understand where the cross-product comes from. Could someone explain this particular part of the derivation? Thanks.

Comment: Did you see Eqn 22 on page 342-343?

Comment: Very funny... I looked it up, it's a reference to a book I don't have and can't seem to download.

Comment: Then I would search for "Newton's second law in a rotating frame."

Comment: it's because in the rotating frame $\frac{dz}{dt} = \omega \times z$

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth it for you reading about differentiating vectors on rotating frames.

- http://envsci.rutgers.edu/~broccoli/dynamics_lectures/lect_06_dyn12_mom_eq_rot.pdf [image: scr1]
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame#Time_derivatives_in_the_two_frames [image: src2]

**Appendix**

In addition, to prove equation (3.28) follow this answer
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/65768/392 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105099/392

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the corresponding equations from Newton's law for rotating objects. So simply:

1. Product rule
2. dz/dt=ω×z