# Relative angular velocity

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

Two bodies are in circular motion with A at one diameter and having velocity tangentially downwards and B at other end of diameter tangentially upwards. Find angular velocity of particle A wrt B if angular velocity of particle A wrt centre of circle is $\omega.$
I tried to do vector subtraction of velocity of A and Velocity of B with angle between them as $\pi$ and got the answer to be $2V.$ Then I tried to apply $V=R\omega$ and got the relative angular velocity as $2\omega.$ But the book shows $\omega$ as answer. Where have I done wrong and how to do it?

Comment: Related?[Relative angular velocity and acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105096/relative-angular-velocity-and-acceleration)

Comment: The two particles maintain a constant distance with each other and hence act as if part of a rigid body => They share a _common_ angular velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose a frame of reference where B is steady, then in that
frame A's velocity is $2V$, as you said. Distance of A from B is $2R$
and angular velocity is $(2V)/(2R) = V/R = \omega$.

Actually this is a theorem in kinematics of rigid bodies: if you
choose several reference frames differing one from another only for a
translational motion velocities do change, but angular velocity
always stays the same.

Comment: That was very clear. Thank you